# Are these two estimators of the coefficient in linear regression with a binary regressor algebraically equivalent?

Tags: regression

Suppose $Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$, where $X_i \in \{0, 1\}$ is binary and assume $E[\epsilon_i \mid X_i] = 0$.

Then the standard linear regression formula is
$$ \hat{\beta} = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})Y_i }{ \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2}.$$

Further, we know that $\beta = E[Y_i \mid X_i = 1] - E[Y_i \mid X_i = 0]$, so that $\beta$ can be estimated by
$$ \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(1-X_i)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)}. $$

Are those two estimator algebraically the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They are. To see this,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i = (1-\bar{X})\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X_i - \bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(1-X_i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}) X_i = (1-\bar{X})\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n(1-\bar{X})\bar{X}$$ then
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2} = (1-\bar{X}) \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2} - \bar{X}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2} = \\ =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(1-X_i)}$$